# Requesting Android Overlay Permission results in different screen shown depending on Android version - can this be avoided?

Tags: android

The following can be used to request Overlay Permission from the user:

```
if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION);
    intent.setData(Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

On API 29 (Android 10) and lower, this results in the following screen where the user can directly switch on the permission.

[image]

On API 30 (Android 11) and higher, the same code results in the following screen, forcing the user to select the app in question first:

[image]

**Does anyone know how you can ensure the first screen is shown in every case to avoid the extra step?**

Comment: This is [a documented change in Android behavior](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/permissions?hl=en#system-alert).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment from CommonsWare: this is a documented change and there is currently no way to avoid the extra step.